# Union Mount in Docker Container

Tags: docker, filesystems, mount, unionfs

In my Docker container there are two directories with a file in each:

```
/foo/file1.txt
/bar/file2.txt
```

How can I mount these directories, such that both files are still acessible?
The result after `mount -t aufs -o dirs=/foo:/bar none /mdst` should look like:

```
$ ls /mdst
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

(I am running the Container and shells inside as `--privileged` and `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN`)

I keep getting
`mount: /mdst: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on none, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

Some research brought me to [this GitHub-Issue](https://github.com/tern-tools/tern/issues/566#issuecomment-593568657), telling me I cant do an overlay-fs in docker containers.

Are there any alternatives to achieve this or did I do something wrong?

Comment: You want the files to be accessible from outside the container?

Comment: No, the union should be a webroot for nginx. Access from outside not needed